# Using trackpad on Lenovo Thinkpad X220 results in 'tab' presses

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

When I use the trackpad on my Thinkpad X220 (42984BU), it seems to result in <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypresses (i.e. it actually has the same effect as if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly). The red TrackPoint (eraserhead) works fine, and clicking on the trackpad's bottom right and left buttons works fine. I suspect that this is a physical malfunction, but I may be wrong. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Side note: On top of this, I also have the common "UltraNav driver is not installed" error, but that may be a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

In common with many newish laptops containing the multi-touch trackpads, I've seen multiple issues on these laptops.

Common problems include the cursor suddenly moving to a new location. I've not seen this specific issue though. I assume that you have checked the settings and haven't changed them? You could also try changing the sensitivity and see if that helps. Also try turning off the advanced trackpad features such as scrolling and zoom.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out a hardware problem either...